# Docker commands succeed on running container, but fail on Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-build

I have some command that I run, for installing Cuda support on Ubuntu 14.04. In order to do it, I run the following command, which is a series of combined commands:

```
apt-get install -y software-properties-common && add-apt-repository -y ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa && apt-get --purge remove "nvidia*" && apt-get --purge remove "cuda*" && cd Downloads && dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1404-7-5-local_7.5-18_amd64.deb && apt-get -y update && apt-get -y upgrade && apt-get install -y cuda
```

- When I do it on a running container, i.e. my Dockerfile only contains the command `FROM ubuntu:14.04`, then I use `docker run -it <my new image name> bash` and it succeeds!
- When I do it from the Dockerfile, it gets a lot of runtime errors, such as:

  ***invoke-rc.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of force-reload.***

  ***invoke-rc.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of start.***

I want to clarify - it succeeds when I run bash on a container and follow the Dockerfile commands step by step, but fails if I execute the same as RUN commands in the dockerfile, using `docker build`.

Any idea what could be the problem and how to solve it?

I want to note that I saw in some places people that add the following command to their dockerfile:

```
RUN echo "#!/bin/sh\nexit 0" > /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d
```

There is nothing more elegant? Isn't it about different permissions when running `docker build` vs `docker run -it` ?

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://jpetazzo.github.io/2013/10/06/policy-rc-d-do-not-start-services-automatically/) is a good post which tries to root cause the issue you are facing.

**Shorter way**:

1. `RUN echo "#!/bin/sh\nexit 0" > /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d` should resolve your issue
    OR
2. If that doesn't resolve the issue, try running your docker container with `privileged` option. Like this, `docker run --privileged -d -ti DOCKER_IMAGE:TAG`

Ideally, I would not recommend running container with `privileged` option unless its a test bed container. The reason being running a docker container with privileged gives all capabilities to the container, and it also lifts all the limitations enforced. In other words, the container can then do almost everything that the host can do. But this is not a good practice. This defeats the docker purpose of isolating from host machine.

The ideal way to do this is to `set capabilities` of your docker container based on what you want to achieve. Googling this should help you out to provide appropriate `capability` for your docker container.

Comment: It is not advisable to run docker with  `--privileged` mode. Docker is mean to isolate from host machine.

Comment: I agree with you @chintanthakar. Probably not the best way and recommended way to run with `--priviledged`. I think the best would be to set capabilities inside the container based on what you are trying to do

Comment: what package is supposed to be installed that contains this policy-rc.d file? this doesn't make a lot of sense...

Comment: oh it contains 'exit 101' inside docker in the ubuntu 20 image